# Flask "Pick-List" Widget

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, flask

I'm trying to create this widget in Flask, to build a pivot table interface:

http://www.richwidgets.io/select/pick-list.html

I'm absolutely hopeless at web programming, and I can't find a clone of this to plug in to Flask anywhere online.

Answer (score 3):

I'd handle this on the front end with JavaScript. There's a number of libraries you can use. I suggest [PivotTable.js](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable).